# detect mobile using wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress plugin development, but any how I have developed two shortcodes i.e. `[MY_SHORTCODE]` and `[MY_SHORTCODE_MOBILE]`, both are working fine but now I want to do one enhancement in it, that is, I want to write a new shortcode which `detect the device`, if the detected device is mobile than I want to call the shortcode `[MY_SHORTCODE_MOBILE]`  otherwise I want to call `[MY_SHORTCODE]`. How can I do this ? please help me guys .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it your problem that you want to run short code base on browser or mobile device.

Download php file for [mobile detect](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) code and put below code where do you want to run short code

```
    <?php
    $useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if(preg_match('/copy paste mobile detect code here from detectmobilebrowser.php',substr($useragent,0,4)))
    {
    //header('Location: http://detectmobilebrowser.com/mobile');
    // that code run for mobile device
    echo do_shortcode("[MY_SHORTCODE_MOBILE]");
    }
    else{
    // that code run for browser
    echo do_shortcode("[MY_SHORTCODE]");
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it via a plugin [Mobile Detector](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mobile-detector/)

or if you want to create your own you can start by using mobile detection library(PHP)

[mobile-detect](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/)

Comment: Yep I can use that php class but how can I call a shortcode in another shortcode

Comment: @lord_linus instead of that i will suggest to use it as base and use the code that plugin is using ..it must be a method so you need to use that method in your method/class and then generate your short code

Comment: actually i am creating a plugin only then how can I use another plugin

Comment: instead i have used the another method : mobile_detect.php, in that i have called the shortcode using echo do_shortcode('[myshortcode]')